# Save data from csv file into datatable

Tags: vb.net

I have a csv file containing the following data/structure:

"UTF-8"
PasswordAdapter,Supervisor.PasswordAdapter,UniqueName,Supervisor.UniqueName
"PasswordAdapter1","PasswordAdapter1","167660","608320"
"PasswordAdapter1","PasswordAdapter1","718090","608320"
"PasswordAdapter1","PasswordAdapter1","613146","608320"

This file is called SharedUserSupervisorExport.csv and resides at a certain location (H:\Somewhere).

First action is to select the file and delete the first row containing "UTF-8".
Selecting the file is no problem. Removing the first row is.

After the first row is removed I would like to save the data to a datatable.

The last action would be to save the datatable to a database table.

I really hope you can help me because I have been stuck at this for a while.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

I have found the code below to do this but I am wondering if it is the best way to do it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim folder = "H:\Somewhere\"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [SharedUserSupervisorExport.csv]", CnStr)
      Adp.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    ' I use the DGV for testing purposes!
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
' Create a variable that holds the path to the CSV file
Dim csvFile = "H:\Somewhere\SharedUserSupervisorExport.csv"

' Create data table
Dim outputTable As DataTable = New DataTable("SharedUserSupervisorExport")

' Create columns
Dim passwordAdapterColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("PasswordAdapter")
Dim supervisorPasswordAdapterColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("SupervisorPasswordAdapter")
Dim uniqueNameColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("UniqueName")
Dim supervisorUniqueNameColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("SupervisorUniqueName")

' Set type for each column
passwordAdapterColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
supervisorPasswordAdapterColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
uniqueNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
supervisorUniqueNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

' Add columns to table
outputTable.Columns.Add(passwordAdapterColumn)
outputTable.Columns.Add(supervisorPasswordAdapterColumn)
outputTable.Columns.Add(uniqueNameColumn)
outputTable.Columns.Add(supervisorUniqueNameColumn)


For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(csvFile, Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1)

    ' Break down line into an array
    Dim fields As String() = Strings.Split(line, ",")

    ' Create new row for data
    Dim row As DataRow = outputTable.NewRow()

    ' Update row with data from array
    row("PasswordAdapter") = fields(0)
    row("SupervisorPasswordAdapter") = fields(1)
    row("UniqueName") = fields(2)
    row("SupervisorUniqueName") = fields(3)

    ' Add row to table
    outputTable.Rows.Add(row)

Next
```

Note that this does not use an OleDbDataAdapter but you can certainly use one like you do in your question. You can adjust the `For Each line` loop to use your OleDbDataAdapter but the code to update the row should similar.

**Edit**

You can use a [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) to handle the CSV:

```
Using parser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(csvFile)

    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

    While Not parser.EndOfData

        Dim fields As String() = parser.ReadFields()

        ' Create new row for data
        Dim row As DataRow = outputTable.NewRow()

        ' Update row with data from array
        row("PasswordAdapter") = fields(0)
        row("SupervisorPasswordAdapter") = fields(1)
        row("UniqueName") = fields(2)
        row("SupervisorUniqueName") = fields(3)

        ' Add row to table
        outputTable.Rows.Add(row)

    End While

End Using
```

TextFieldParser is not a very efficient class but in this case I think it will do the job.

Comment: Dear Étienne,
Thank you very much for your help.
I have read through your code example and besides the fact that it works great it also makes sense.

The only thing that is left for me is to get rid of the quotations.
I've put a replace when the row with data from the array gets filled like this:
 ' Update row with data from array
      row("PasswordAdapter") = fields(0).Replace("""", "")
      .....
The above code works and removes the double quotes.
Is this the best way to remove the double qoutes ?
Or would it be better to do it another way ?

Comment: @Johnny, if your previous OleDbDataAdapter handled the double quotes properly, you can use that instead of `File.ReadLines`. Just Fill a data set (`Dim ds As DataSet = Adp.Fill(dt)`) and loop through all rows using something like `For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows`

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you consider it answered your original question.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville You might want to set `parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True`.

Comment: I've marked the solution as accepted.
Thank you very much for all of your help!